# How to add filter properties to django rest model and serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a client and broadcast model. the client model contains a tag field and operator_code field. I would like to be able to a filter property to be able to filter by tags and or operator_code when creating a new broadcast object.

models.py

```
class Broadcast(models.Model):

date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
end_date = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.text

class Client(models.Model):
phoneRegex = RegexValidator(regex='^7[0-9]{10}$')
phone = models.CharField(validators=[phoneRegex], max_length=11, unique=True)
tag = TaggableManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.phone

@property
def operator_code(self):
    
    return self.phone[1:4]

@property
def time_zone(self):
    ru_number = phonenumbers.parse(self.phone, 'RU')
    time_zone = timezone.time_zones_for_number(ru_number)
    return time_zone
```

Serializers.py

```
class ClientSerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
tag = TagListSerializerField()
time_zone = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
operator_code = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified', 'operator_code', 'time_zone',)

def validate(self, attrs):
    phone_number_exists = Client.objects.filter(phone=attrs['phone']).exists()

    if phone_number_exists:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(detail="phone number exists")
    
    if attrs['phone'][0] != '7':
        raise serializers.ValidationError(detail="phone number must start with 7")
    
    if len(attrs['phone']) != 11:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(detail="phone number must be 11 digits")
    
    return super().validate(attrs)

def get_operator_code(self, obj):
    return obj.operator_code

def get_time_zone(self, obj):
    return obj.time_zone

class BroadcastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
class Meta:
    model = Broadcast
    fields = ['text', 'end_date',]
    read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified', 'filter_client',)
```

Comment: If it's during the create process, is it validators rather than filters that you want to add?

Comment: during the create process or update for the broadcast, i want the ability to add filter by tags from the client model as well as the operator code that is, the message will only be sent to the clients that matches the tag or tags or the operator code